# How do I use Crosstalk in Shiny to filter a reactive data table?

Tags: r, shiny

I cannot use functions from the Crosstalk package in a Shiny app. When running, I receive an error message saying my SharedData object is not found.

I would like to create a Shiny app where users can filter in various ways (selectInput, selecting rows in a data table, etc.) but all tables, charts and maps update simultaneously regardless of the filter method. I have heard that crosstalk is good for this and I have relied on the volcano example [here](https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/) as a template.

My issue is that when I attempt to run my app, I receive a warning saying that the SharedData object cannot be found. I've tried placing this in the server part, and tried placing within reactive, eventReactive, observe, observeEvent, etc. but these don't make any difference. I've also tried placing the code outside of both ui and server parts but the only difference is that my error is now "object of type 'environment' is not subsettable".

Below is not my original code; I have simplified the issue and made it reproducible by sharing the following:
*Created a new Shiny app from Rstudio (the template uses the faithful dataset)
*Modified the dataset from faithful to iris
*Added a call to the crosstalk library
*Included filter_select, SharedData calls
*Modified line 48 to refer to shared_df rather than iris

```
library(shiny)
library(crosstalk)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram

ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Crosstalk test"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30),
         filter_select("rows", "Select rows:",
                       shared_df,
                       ~Species,
                       multiple = TRUE)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Shared data available for use by the crosstalk package
  shared_df <- SharedData$new(iris)

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- shared_df[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My expected results should include a histogram chart with interactive slider to dynamically adjust bin widths (as per the "old faithful" template). In addition, I should be able to select Species of plant and the histogram should dynamically update to only display results for the selected Species.

*** edit ***
I've managed to recreate the volcano example linked to above for a Shiny app. The code below works:

```
library(shiny)
library(crosstalk)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)

# Wrap data frame in SharedData
# Use SharedData like a dataframe with Crosstalk-enabled widgets

sd <- SharedData$new(quakes[sample(nrow(quakes), 100),])

ui <- fluidPage(
# Create a filter input
filter_slider("mag", "Magnitude", sd, column=~mag, step=0.1, width=250),
bscols(leafletOutput("map"), DTOutput("table"))
)


server <- function(input,output) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({ leaflet(sd) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers()})

  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(sd, extensions="Scroller", style="bootstrap", class="compact", width="100%",
            options=list(deferRender=TRUE, scrollY=300, scroller=TRUE))
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The only difference between this volcano example and my iris example is (apart from moving the shared_df outside of ui and server) the usage of filter_select. When I move shared_df a different error is returned: "Warning: Error in [: object of type 'environment' is not subsettable"

Comment: Your `shared_df` is defined in `server` and you use it in `ui`. That cannot work. Try to define it at the beginning, outside `server` and `ui`.

Comment: Thanks Stephane, but I have tried this and it returned a different error: "object of type 'environment' is not subsettable". I've managed to make the volcano example referred to above work fine in Shiny so I think something else must be occurring. I've edited the question as a result...

Comment: This error is generated by `shared_df[, 2]`. Replace with `shared_df$origData()[,2]`.

Comment: This change allows me to plot, but the histogram doesn't update based on the selection held in filter_select. Should this be changed to shared_df$data(...)?

Comment: Sorry I don't  know. I have never used shared dataframes.